# How to bound a indentifier to a procedure?

Tags: recursion, lambda, scheme, racket

Im trying to write a procedure (apply a b)
That applies 'a' to a number for 'b' times. 
This is my answer but ı dont know how to bound x to the procedure (apply a b).
 For example (apply inc 3) 2)=>5
Thank you.

```
(define apply
  (lambda (a b) 
    compose
    (a b)
    (if (<= b 0)  
        x
        (a x (apply a (- b 1))))))

(define compose 
  (lambda (f g) 
    (lambda (x) (f (g x)))))
```

Comment: `apply` needs to return a function of one argument, but doesn't. Also know that redefining `apply` might not be allowed since it is a primitive function in Scheme.

Comment: You seem to have all the right pieces, but you're assembling them in the wrong order. `compose` takes two functions, not  a function and a number. Think about what the function `(apply f 0)` should do. Try to think of a lambda expression that does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I would encourage you to follow the steps of the design recipe as it appears in [How To Design Programs](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/). Specifically, it looks to me like you could really use a purpose statement and *test cases* that you formulated yourself.